# How to set path in cronscript

Tags: shell-script, files, cron

I am running a cronscript like:

`*/45 * * * * /path/to/php /path/to/file.php`

it creates a file and put on home directory; But I want to create this file in my desired path like:

`*/45 * * * * /path/to/php /path/to/file.php /path/where/file/to/save`

actually the file.php create file.xls and put it on home directory. I want to set path for file.xls should be created in some other directory.

is there some way ?

Comment: it's not quite clear what you want, i think it is easier to just create php script and everything do inside and just put path to the script in cron.

Comment: How is the file created? You probably have a file name in your `php` script, just change that file name.

Comment: Hello everyone, actually the file.php create file.xls and put it on home directory. I want to set path for file.xls should be created in some other directory. is it clear?

Comment: @RajaRassani no. We need to see your `php` script. This has nothing to do with cron, you have written the script to create the file in the home directory. Just change that.

Comment: Hi @RajaRassani that needs to be configured in your php script. Instead of just using the `file.xls`, use `PATH/file.xls`

Comment: ... or if its using the current working directory, `cd /path/you/want && /path/to/php…` might work. But really, you ought to just edit the PHP script to take a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PHP script creates the file in the current directory, change to the desired output directory:

```
*/45 * * * * cd /path/where/file/to/save && /path/to/php /path/to/file.php
```

If the PHP script creates the file in your home directory, you might be able to pretend your home directory is elsewhere — but if it also tries to read other files from your home directory, then it will also read these files from elsewhere.

```
*/45 * * * * HOME=/path/where/file/to/save /path/to/php /path/to/file.php
```